# How to solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}^4 y}{\mathrm{d} x^4}-2{\frac{\mathrm{d^3}y}{\mathrm{d} x^3}}+2{\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y }{\mathrm{d} x^2}}+y=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve the equation

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^4 y}{\mathrm{d} x^4}-2{\frac{\mathrm{d^3}y}{\mathrm{d} x^3}}+2{\frac{\mathrm{d^2}y }{\mathrm{d} x}}+y=0$$

by writing its Auxiliary Equation

$$
m^{4}-2m^{3}+2m^{2}+1=0,
$$

But now I am unable to solve this polynomial.

Comment: Well, that is [no surprise](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+m%5E4-2m%5E3%2B2m%5E2%2B1%3D0) at all... (but there is in fact a [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots); even though it is not pretty).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh sorry... Yes thats what I meant

Comment: @mrtaurho is there any other method?

Comment: Not really. $~$

Comment: Could predict roughly what $y$ looks like. E.g $y=ae^{bx}$ and see what happens.

Comment: What's the origin of the equation? I suspect you may be looking at an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) , pun half-intended...

Comment: I think you'd have to approximate the roots.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Of course OP knew this. How else would they be trying to solve an eigenequation?

Comment: By the way, @Jalaj I think the third summand on LHS should have the denominator $\mathrm dx^2$ instead, no?

Comment: @Allawonder Give a student a list of formulae. Would they necessarily know why they use a given formula?

Comment: @AlvinLepik Well, I don't know why someone wouldn't know this. It's basic. Why would you just use a formula you don't *understand*? I mean, that's the first thing. Also, I didn't assume OP was a student; thus, I thought they simply skipped the obvious step of substituting the exponential Ansatz, since one can often tell the characteristic equation at a glance after some experience with doing it the usual way. In sum, I guess my main point is that I assumed OP knew how they got from the differential equation to the algebraic one and simply ommitted to type the details since it would be...

Comment: ...unnecessary to state that for anyone who would likely answer their question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is given by $$m=1/2+1/6\,\sqrt {3}\sqrt {{\frac { \left( -10+6\,i\sqrt {111} \right) ^
{2/3}-\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}+16}{\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}
}}}}+1/6\,\sqrt {-3\,{\frac { \left( -10+6\,i\sqrt {111} \right) ^{2/3
}\sqrt {{\frac { \left( -10+6\,i\sqrt {111} \right) ^{2/3}-\sqrt [3]{-
10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}+16}{\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}}}}+6\,\sqrt {3}
\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}+2\,\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}\sqrt 
{{\frac { \left( -10+6\,i\sqrt {111} \right) ^{2/3}-\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i
\sqrt {111}}+16}{\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}}}}+16\,\sqrt {{\frac {
 \left( -10+6\,i\sqrt {111} \right) ^{2/3}-\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {
111}}+16}{\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}}}}}{\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {
111}}\sqrt {{\frac { \left( -10+6\,i\sqrt {111} \right) ^{2/3}-\sqrt [
3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}+16}{\sqrt [3]{-10+6\,i\sqrt {111}}}}}}}}
$$

Comment: This is unlikely what OP needed. :) No one does this in real life. Just approximate instead.

Comment: You know this after a few seconds to read? Nice!

Comment: That's why i posted another nicer looking solution by Maple!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: oh dear.. +1 simply for having the fortitude/mental capacity to type this up or at least making it look like that's the case

Answer (score -1):

go to wolfram alpha
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=complex+z+%3A++z%5E4%E2%88%922*z%5E3%2B2*z%5E2%2B1%3D0
if you don't want to use the awful formula